# defer log.SetOutput(os.Stdout) after log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)

Tags: logging, go, nsq, go-nsq

In `go-nsq` library (https://github.com/bitly/go-nsq/blob/master/writer_test.go#L38), I found the following code:

```
log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
defer log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
```

Why does the author defer logging to stdout after discard the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)` statement changes the standard logger output destination. The `defer log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)` statement attempts to reset the output destination back to its initial value when the function ends. However, it should have reset it back to `os.Stderr`.

[src/pkg/log/log.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go)

```
var std = New(os.Stderr, "", LstdFlags)
```

Comment: Thanks, @peterSO! Why would the author want to dump the log to `/dev/null` and set it back later? Isn't logging the error in Unit Test a favorable thing?

Comment: @Mingyu: The tests only care that there is no error, that is, err == nil. The text of logged informational and error messages is considered to be unimportant or clutter. Run the tests without discarding the logged messages. Does it look sensible to discard them?